# Changing a webpage to a 'directory'

Tags: php, html, directory

I'm not sure how you call it, but could anyone help me with this problem:
Is there a way to set a .php file to a directory.

Example:
I have 2 files in the same directory: onepage.php and secondpage.php. If I want to visit index.php I would go to ..../onepage.php (lets say: www.stackoverflow.com/onepage.php). Then, if I want to visit the second page I would go to www.stackoverflow.com/secondpage.php. However, is there a way to make it so it's visible as www.stackoverflow.com/secondpage?

Also, if I take the same example, and let's say I have a $_GET at my secondpage.php, is there also a way to do www.stackoverflow.com/secondpage/($_GET value) ?

Thanks.

Comment: quick win would be to add a folder in your root, called secondpage then add an index.php file, add the code to capture the get request

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `mod_rewrite` for your Apache server and `.htaccess` to set the rules to effectively rewrite the visible URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file.Like this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule secondpage/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

Now `$_GET['var1']` is your variable.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS WORKING CODE COPIED FROM MY WEBSITE**

create a file called .htaccess

add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Run everything else but real files through parse.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|html|js|json|jpg|jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ parse.php?info=$1 [L]
```

Now in your parse.php file have this code:

```
<?php

$getVars = $_GET['info'];
$vars = explode("/",$getVars);

if(count($vars)<1){
 $vars[0] = "home";
 $vars[1] = "index";
}else if(count($vars)<2){
 $vars[1] = "index";
}


 $fileString = $vars[0] . '/' . $vars[1] . '.php';
if(file_exists($fileString)){
  include_once($fileString);
}else{
  include_once("error/404.php");
}
```

Now add file like:

directory: mydirectory
file: index.php

Access as myurl.com/mydirectory/